# Combine two lists without duplicate values

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
list1 = ["palani", "samy","be"]
list2 = ["palani", "samys","be"]

def find_common(list1,list2):
    for x in list1:
      for y in list2:
        if x == y :
          list2.remove(x) 


    print" unique string 1:",list1
    print" unique string 2:",list2
    print" combained string 2:",list1.append(list2)


find_common(list1,list2)
```

[image]

Why am I getting `None`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

np.unique(list1+list2) # keeps only non dublicates
```

this is also keeps the order incase that was a priority

Comment: This works, but I think numpy is a pretty heavy package for doing this, when you can also do it with standard python operations.

Answer (score 11):

This could be accomplished by using set:

```
a = ['hello', 'world']
b = ['hello', 'universe']

unique = list(set(a + b))

print(unique)

# ['universe', 'hello', 'world']
```

Note: this won't work for a list of dictionaries!

Answer (score 2):

The `list.append` method modifies the list in-place and returns `None`. You should use the `+` operator to merge the two lists instead.

Change:

```
print" combained string 2:",list1.append(list2)
```

to:

```
print" combained string 2:",list1+list2
```

Answer (score 2):

```
list3 = list1[:]
[list3.append(i) for i in list2 if i not in list1] 

print(l3)
```

> ```
> ['palani', 'samy', 'be', 'samys']
> ```

Answer (score 1):

you may try:

```
def find_common(list1,list2):
    return list(set(list1+list2))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `set` operations to achieve this.

```
unique = list(set(list1).symmetric_difference(set(list2)))
```